# i have a number of different groups with their populatons and the average life expectacy and in i need a formula to determine statistical difference

Tags: probability

this is the data that i have and would like to determine if there was a significant difference between the groups as to average age at death

I do not have the original raw data

Class of occupation   number               average age at death

Medical                244                                67.31
Lawyer                 294                                68.14
Clergy                 945                                69.49
Members of Royals      97                                 64.04
Aristocracy            179                                67.31
Gentry                 1632                               70.22
Literature and Scienc  395                                67.55
Arts                   239                                65.96
Trade and Commerce     513                                68.74
Officers of Royal Navy 36                                 68.40
Officers of Army       569                                67.07
Learned Professions    1483                               68.86

Class of occupation   number               average age at death

Medical                244                                67.31
Lawyer                 294                                68.14
Clergy                 945                                69.49
Members of Royals      97                                 64.04
Aristocracy            179                                67.31
Gentry                 1632                               70.22
Literature and Scienc  395                                67.55
Arts                   239                                65.96
Trade and Commerce     513                                68.74
Officers of Royal Navy 36                                 68.40
Officers of Army       569                                67.07
Learned Professions    1483                               68.86

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you have the variances of the groups, or do you just have the sizes and the means?

Comment: Estimates of average life expectancy are not based on simple averages but from life tables, themselves based on detailed information about population exposed to risk of death at each age during the study period and deaths at each age. Without a great deal of detail about the calculation of each estimate (which *might* be gleanable from the original reports they originate from) there's little hope of being able to perform any test.